# Is there a way to display custom text in telerik radgrid instead of numeric values?

Tags: telerik

I have a radgrid with a column that displays values('0','1','2') from my database, each respectively representing ("TPA","Cash Claim","Normal Claim").

is there a way to display the texts for the corresponding values instead of the numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the contents of each row on Item Databound in your code behind.  If you're using C# you can copy this example, in your itemDataBound you just need to check what the value is, and set the column text to what you'd like to show instead.

```html
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgMyStuff" OnItemDataBound="rgMyStuff_ItemDataBound">
```

```js
protected void rgMyStuff_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (!(e.Item is GridDataItem)) return;
 GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
    //I like to cast my gridDataItem back to the type that I initially set in DataSource
    MyStruct dataItem = (MyStruct)dataBoundItem.DataItem;
 if (dataItem.myType == 1)
          dataBoundItem["MyType"].Text = "TPA";
    
    //or you could also just use the DataBoundItem like this:
    if(dataBoundItem["MyType"].Text == "1")
            databoundItem["MyType"].Text = "TPA";
 ...
}
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what are you referring to by MyStruct?

Comment: I usually have an object that I set as the DataSource, i was just saying you can cast your databoundItem back to whatever that object you passed in.  IE:  rgMyStuff.datasource =    List<MyStruct>